# My 12:57 Acrostic Riddle

Tags: riddle, word

My altered name is lurking slyly here
As my self-referential words make clear.
You've guessed my easy riddle now, I fear.

Answer?

A hint:

> The title could have been: "My 25% Odds Acrostic Riddle"

Another hint:

> https://www.google.ch/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=acrostic
>  In this case, I used another marker

Hinting again, and summarizing clues from comments

> One piece of punctuation was a misdirection
>  All parts of the puzzle (everything above "A hint:") are significant
>  This is not a usual acrostic. The title is a key or map to the solution

For instance

> The "My" in the title is a clue that the word "my" is the acrostic marker
>  3 2 1 is not an ordering and the digits may mean different things

There is always a trick

> The word "self-referential" applies in more than one way here
>  There is a certain tricky sense in which this puzzle is indeed easy

Want something specific?

> There are six letters in the solution.

Comment: This is my first composition and I wasn't sure how hard to make it. Some of the answers to other puzzles seemed supernaturally brilliant. I believe adding the word "acrostic" makes it fairer. Good luck to all!

Comment: Wait. It's an acrostic? Now it's a dead giveaway: the answer is BENGHAZI

Comment: @question_asker you've been watching too many debates.

Comment: The title gives a key to the way the acrostic works. One piece of punctuation is a misdirection. The word "self-reference" works on several levels. When you find the solution, you will understand why it can be considered an easy riddle.

Comment: You're killing me, Hugh.

Comment: One thing I appreciated about this: you were able to give hints that were actually just hints - a lot of times people get so frustrated that their puzzle wasn't solved that they practically give away the answer in "hints".

Comment: @HughMeyers nice... it was driving me crazy!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Answer?

> yes, it is.

Because:

> The title indeed gives away the key, "My". It also tells how to use it with 12:57 which can also be stated as 3 to 1, homophone for 321.  For the **3** "my"s you take the next **2** words and use their **1**st letter.  My **a**ltered **n**ame, my **s**elf-referential **w**ords, my **e**asy **r**iddle.  It is, in fact, easy because you give it away with the last line.

Comment: aha. so "referential" doesn't count as a word

Comment: Well done! Hopefully I can strike a better balance between challenging and impossible if I do another puzzle. I do hope you enjoyed the chase.

Comment: @question_asker "self-referential" is a hyphenated word. I was afraid people were miscounting so I referred to it as "the word" in a comment and in a hint. Sorry about that.

Comment: @HughMeyers No need to apologize for that! If I had correctly interpreted the appropriate hint in the first place, I would have thought to "ignore" it as a word

Comment: How does 12:57 become 3 to 1?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes As in three minutes until one o'clock.  What time is it?  It's three to one.

Comment: @Kevin oh, I see. I'm used to 24h time. Thanks!

Comment: even in 24h time, 3 to 1 still happens once a day

Comment: How is it 6 characters in the answer? According to the last hint in the question, it doesn't fit, does it?

Comment: The first spolier part is tongue-in-cheek.  For the correct six-letter answer check the bold letters in the second spoiler part

Answer (score 20):

The time 12:57 is

> Three minutes to 1

And 25% odds are

> Three to one

And the pattern of lines is

> 3, then 1

So the "name" is

> 321

Since we have 3 lines, and the word acrostic in the title, we can use the first letter of each line, in this order:

> Y A M

But then it says "altered" meaning we can use whatever order we like after all.

> Of the permutations AYM, AMY, MAY, MYA, YAM, and YMA, May is possibly a name,

but I think

> Amy

Is more clearly and obviously a name.

Comment: How is 321 a name?

Comment: Spoilers, dude! Anyway that's why I used quotes

Comment: Getting warmer... but look for a word not a number. You are part way there.

Comment: @HughMeyers I carried it further after your edit

Comment: In India, Yam is the name of the god of death...

Comment: @ermanen the end of the second-last spoiler block mentions the other, but I feel the one I chose is more clearly a name, even though that other was a first name in the past... then again you could claim that two names out of 8 permutations is indeed 25% odds as mentioned in a hint. :-)

Comment: @manshu I've known more than one Maryam who has gone by "Yam"

Comment: @KateGregory But then (2/8) it's not a name, it's names.

Comment: seems like you have the right answer, although it is a bit strange that the title tells you to pick the letters in the correct order only to tell you to order them however you want in the first line. Kind of makes the whole 12:57 part pointless.

Comment: @DasBeasto The title technically only gives you *an* order to put the letters in, and any order other than the normal order is necessarily "altered"

Comment: isn't 25% odds 4 to 1?

Comment: @Alex no, 25% odds for you means 75% for the other side; 3 to 1. 4 to 1 would be 1 in 5 for you, 4 in 5 for the other side; 20%

Comment: @Alex "3 to 1 odds" *technically* means you have three chances to win and one chance to lose, so it's not exactly the same as 25% chance (which, incidentally, would be "1 *in* 4 odds")

Comment: Got it Kate / question_asker, thanks

Answer (score 15):

> Me

Explanation:

> **1.** it's a different ('altered') version of one's name. 
> **2.** It's self-referential. 
>  **3.** It's the 12th and 57th letter of the question respectively (see the title - 12:57).
>  **4.** It's answered by the time you read the third line which says 'You've guessed my easy riddle now' i.e. before the third line, the answer is apparent.

Comment: Well, this *has* to be it. Nice work!

Comment: @question_asker thanks! let's see what the author had in mind...

Comment: Well worth an upvote! As a coincidence, it's in the Psalm 46 league.

Comment: @HughMeyers this comment of yours makes me wonder if the answer is 'luke'... :o

Comment: @manshu lmao Luke 12:57 (NIV) is "Why don't you judge for yourselves what is right?"

Comment: @question_asker does it mean that i can accept it as my personal answer...coz it's me to judge for myself...:D

Comment: @manshu Do what you want, I'm not the cops

Answer (score 10):

Your name could be

> My alter**ed na**me is lur**king sly**ly here As my self-referential words make clear. You've guessed my easy riddle now, I fear.

But it probably isn't

It's probably

> MAY, based on the work some others have done (12:57 $\rightarrow$ "three to one" $\rightarrow$ 3 2 1 $\rightarrow$ Y A M + "altered" $\rightarrow$ MAY), as well as the "acrostic" part of the hint.

And yet! It could *also* be

> ***ESA*** (this sounds like a stretch, but the last couple of attempts from myself and Kate Gregory were rejected) based on "acrostic" and OP's hint that his *marker* had changed. Self-referential words could refer to the recurring "my", and the first letter after each "my" are A, S, and E, in that order. Giving them the 3-2-1 treatment mentioned by Kate Gregory, we get Esa, which the internet *assures* me is a name.
>
>  <sub>If we're *also* taking "altered" into account, the name could be "SEA". Yes, I literally know a person named Sea.</sub>

Comment: Wow. I didn't see that. An upvote for seeing a solution the author didn't,

Comment: If the answer is "may", it's a very lame puzzle. Especially if the reason it's "may" is that the rhyme leads you to take the first letters of the puzzle in a non-standard order, and then "scramble" them into some other order, when doing so is equivalent to just saying "Take the first letters of the lines, in the natural reading order." That's almost like saying, "Can you figure out my name? It's an anagram of 'David Richerby'."

Comment: @DavidRicherby I think you have misaddressed your complaint.

Comment: @question_asker Since we don't yet know what the "official" answer is, I don't see anywhere to post "If that's the answer, the question is bad", except below the answer.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Maybe you should have waited then.

Comment: Very close now. The title requires a slightly different interpretation. I do hope you enjoy the solution.

Comment: @HughMeyers That gives me an idea but I can't make it fit

Answer (score 7):

I suspect your name is

> **M**y altered name is lurking slyly here
> **A**s my self-referential words make clear.
> **Y**ou've guessed my easy riddle now, I fear.
> **A**nswer?

How this fits (in my opinion):

> Maya is a common female name. The clues 'self-referential' and 'lurking slyly' make me think I'm onto something by picking up the initials of each line. Also, Maya sounds like the last name [Meyers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18924/hugh-meyers) of the OP, which is where 'altered name' fits well.

Comment: I think this is almost right. I don't think the final letter is necessary.

Comment: HOw does it comply to the hint that it's supposed to be six characters?

Comment: @KonradViltersten: The 6 letters hint came MUCH later than my answer. Most of the incorrect answers came before the last hint.

Answer (score 7):

Very similar to @KateGregory 's answer, my guess would be

> YAM

because

> 3 to one ~ three two one ~ line three, line two, line one

thats not a good answer, I fear

but something something here

rhyming is difficult, my dear

second guess

> man (3 2 1 of name, as in *altered name*)

Comment: Warmer still...

Answer (score 5):

I agree with manshu's answer (unfortunately, now deleted) but have a different reasoning.

The answer is

> Hugh Meyers.

Here's why:

> The 'acrostic' refers to the first *word* of each line: My As You (technically "You've" for the last). Motivated by Kate Gregory's 3-2-1, the 12:57 is 3-to-1, which leaves 2 last. Taking this as the word order, we get You My As, which is a 'slyly lurking' and 'altered' version that sounds like "Hugh Meyers", the OP's name. It's a self-referential riddle, referencing the OP's self; and 'easy' because the actual name is in full view.

The hints:

> The '25% Odds' is 1:3, as Kate Gregory points out in comments below her answer. If we read this a "one to three", it *could* be considered a hint to swap the first and third words, reducing to the above line of reasoning. I'm not sure what to make of the second hint, except that it highlights the acrostic as a large part of the puzzle.

Comment: I'm still not totally convinced on the 12:57 thing (and I suspect I won't be until OP confirms it) but this is the most convincing answer yet.

Answer (score 2):

the word is "easy"!!

**My** altered name is **lurking** slyly here

As **my** self-referential **words** make clear.

You've guessed **my** **easy** riddle now, I fear.

Comment: Some of the thinking here is very close to the mark.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer (based off the authors comment to @got it):

> Ire. (It's a name) 
>  The first letter of the 3rd word after the 1st 'my' is 'I'. The first letter of the 2nd word after the 2nd 'my' is 'r'. And the first letter of the 1st word after the 3rd 'my' is 'e'.
>  The 321 refers to the 'my' which is '123', as an anchor for the 3rd 2nd 1st words after them. 
>  Long shot....

Comment: Ire is a name? Can you give an example of somebody called that? ("Ira", sure, but I've never heard of anyone called "Ire". Wikipedia doesn't have a page about anyone called Ire; see [list of all pages with titles beginning "Ire"](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3APrefixIndex&prefix=Ire+&namespace=0) and use your web browser's text search to look for "Ire" with a space after it.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby [here](http://www.babycenter.com/baby-names-ire-971545.htm) and [here](http://www.nordicnames.de/wiki/Ire). I had no idea that such a name exists... said it was a long shot... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Building up on the rest of solutions. The hints relative to the text itself I think have been covered already. Yet nobody seems to pay much attention to

> the "acrostic" part of the title, meaning that the first letter of each line gives the answer.

Therefore it should be

> MAY